# Converting a Java String to Windows-1258

Tags: java, character-encoding, internationalization

A special request to all of the Vietnamese natives out there ;-).

I am trying to convert a plain Java String to a byte array using the [Windows-1258](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1258) code page. The content in this String is in Vietnamese but that should not be much of a problem seeing as Windows-1258 was designed with Vietnamese in mind. Sadly though, certain characters are not being converted properly.

My test case:

```
final Charset wcp1258 = Charset.forName("Cp1258");

final String text = "Việt là khó khăn";
byte[] textArr = text.getBytes(wcp1258);

for (int i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("'%s' maps to: 0x%x", text.charAt(i), textArr[i]));
}
```

Which ends up being:

```
'V' maps to: 0x56
'i' maps to: 0x69
'ệ' maps to: 0x3f <--
't' maps to: 0x74
' ' maps to: 0x20
'l' maps to: 0x6c
'à' maps to: 0xe0
' ' maps to: 0x20
'k' maps to: 0x6b
'h' maps to: 0x68
'ó' maps to: 0xf3
' ' maps to: 0x20
'k' maps to: 0x6b
'h' maps to: 0x68
'ă' maps to: 0xe3
'n' maps to: 0x6e
```

Where you can see that one character is mapped to `3f`, which is the question mark in [Windows-1258](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1258).

I have done a little research and have found out that Windows-1258 creates certain characters by combining diacritical marks. Exactly one of these characters got mapped to the question mark.

How do I get this to convert properly? I think the problem may be related to there not being valid conversions for certain unicode characters to the combinations that are required for Windows-1258. I have tried to add the `Normalizer` class to the mix but without much success.

In case you are wondering, I need this encoding to control a receipt printer. The receipt printer takes either a Windows-1258 or TCVN3 byte array for Vietnamese.

Comment: On which JRE is this running?

Comment: How silly of me. This is "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)" I am not able to update to 8 right now because of legacy.

Comment: The linked Wikipedia page states that `Windows-1258 may not always round trip Unicode encoded Vietnamese due to Unicode normalization differences.` - maybe this is related to the problem

Comment: Any reason to not use UTF-8?

Comment: i must delete last `(%s)` to make your snippet work

Comment: My apologies for that, that was a leftover from some prior work.

Comment: What exactly do you expect as a mapping for the 1258 code page? I guess it's a multi-byte sequence. Does it exist? (Note that your code sample assumes a char-for-byte mapping, not multi-byte sequences)

Comment: As a matter a fact. I am looking into this as we speak, but I have not been able to find out yet how to actually make this combining of diacritical marks happen. So if there is anyone who could tell me if that is even possible, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can not find a better solution, you can always create your own mapping from Unicode to bytes to send to the device.

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer because this is what I ended up doing. I am using an Epson TM70II receipt printer, and even though it contains the Windows-1258 codepage, it does not seem to be able to combine diacritical marks with ordinary characters.

So, I went with the TCVN-3 codepage, which contains all special characters needed. I wrote a class (which I cannot share) to map unicode to TCVN-3. The odd thing about TCVN-3 is that it has a separate codepage for capital letters, but by cleverly switching between the codepages everything works smoothly.